# If there is a faithful simple module then the ring is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Suppose $R$ is a commutative, unital ring and $M$ is a faithful (i.e. $\text{Ann}_R M = 0$) and simple (i.e. no submodules other than $0$ and itself) module. I need to show that $R$ is a field.

The hint says to use that if $f: N\to M$ is a nontrivial homomorphism then $M \cong N/\ker f$, but I don't see how to use it.  $M$ being faithful implies that for all $r$ we have a nontrivial homomorphism $m \mapsto rm$, which I think might be useful.

I would prefer hints over answers.

Comment: What does the simplicity of $M$ tell you about the kernel of the map $m\mapsto rm$? And how does that fit with the faithfulness assumption? Recall the definition of the annihilator...

Comment: @DouglasMolin By simplicity it is $M$ or $0$, and by faithfulness it can’t be $M$, so it is $0$.

Comment: This forgoing comments only establish that $R$ embeds in $End(M_R)$, and that each homomorphism induced by multiplication is a unit in $End(M_R)$, but not that $R$ is a field.  Something more is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more helpful hint would be to consider the map $f:R\to M$ given by $1\mapsto m$ where $m$ is anything nonzero in $M$.  This yields a homomorphism of $R$ **onto** $M$ (why?).

By the third isomorphism theorem, $R/\ker(f)\cong M$ as $R$ modules, and by correspondence $\ker(f)$ is a maximal ideal. But since $R$ is a commutative ring, any element of $\ker(f)$ is going to annihilate $M$, which means $\ker(f)=\{0\}$ by faithfulness.

So the zero ideal is $R$ is maximal: this only happens (in a commutative ring) when $R$ is a field.

Comment: Thank you. Are the following correct? For the "why", the image is a nonzero submodule of $M$. To show that the kernel is $0$, if $a$ is in the kernel then $am = 0$, so $m$ is in the kernel of $a \mapsto ax$ and since $m\ne 0$ it follows by what was shown that $a = 0$.

Comment: If $a\in\ker(f)$, then $aM=\{0\}$, hence $a=0$. That's why $\ker(f)$ is the zero ideal.  You are right about the first question.

Comment: why does $aM = 0$? Isn’t $m$ a preselected element of $M$?

Comment: Isomorphic modules have equal annihilators.  Since $a$ annihilates $R/\ker(f)$, it annihilates $M$.  The element $m$ is no longer important after you've established an isomorphism $M\cong R/\ker(f)$.

Comment: Right, thank you